# Rendering wordpress form with editor as ajax response is not working properly

Tags: ajax, wordpress, editor

In one of my project in wordpress, I tried to create a custom theme options with different fields. but I face an issue when I tried to load a form using ajax with text editor . The rendered editor comes with style and javascript issues, ie the text color becomes white and editor buttons were not visible, also the text and visual toggle not working. I think I need to run some javascript or I miss some js file which could be called in the rendered html, I am attaching the screenshot with this message ang my rendering html code is as follow, This form is renered as inner html in admin area

```
<form id="bgntheme_option_form" action="#" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li class="li-first">
      <div class="option-field">Home Page Header</div>
      <div class="option-value">
        <?php
            $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'bgntheme_home_header' );         
            wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );        
        ?>
        <p class="field-info">Header textarea for homepage.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="clear-both"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="update-form">
      <button id="bgntheme_submit" name="general-settings-submit" value="Update-General" >Update</button>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

[image: Screenshot of loaded editor in ajax response form]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following snippet to your ajax success method:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'your_editor_id' );
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'your_editor_id' );
```

please replace `your_editor_id` with id of editor.

**UPDATE**

You can try this:

1) HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="li-first">
  <div class="option-field">Home Page Header</div>
  <div class="option-value">
    <?php
       $settings = array('media_buttons' => false, 'textarea_name' => 'bgntheme_home_header' );         
        wp_editor( '', 'my_editor', $settings );        
    ?>
    <p class="field-info">Header textarea for homepage.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear-both"></div>
</li>
<li class="update-form">
  <button id="bgntheme_submit" name="general-settings-submit" value="Update-General" >Update</button>      
</li>
```

2) JS

```
success : function( response ) { 
        jQuery('#content-wrapper-inner').html(response); 
        jQuery('#content-wrapper-inner').fadeIn("slow",function‌​() {   
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'my_editor' ); 
            tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'my_editor' ); 
        }); 
 }
```

Comment: This is what I did  In html
$editor_id = "your_editor_id";
    $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'bgntheme_home_header' );   
    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
In ajax respose success
success : function( response ) { 
     jQuery('#content-wrapper-inner').html(response);
     jQuery('#content-wrapper-inner').fadeIn("slow",function() {      
      tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'your_editor_id' );
      tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'your_editor_id' );
     });
    }

Still not working, whether I miss something else

Comment: first you need to update `your_editor_id` its your editor id.

Comment: editor id is correct, I put the same for time being "your_editor_id"

"Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined"  in my console

Comment: if not worked please fallow this link with another options https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-to-load-wp-editor-through-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 1):

I had your problem and I solved it.
In your call back function in your javascript file add this code:

```
quicktags({id : 'your_editor_id'});
tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, 'your_editor_id' );
```

hear is an example :

```
$.ajax({
        url: data.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        success : function (response) {
            $('.row').append(String(response));
            quicktags({id : 'your_editor_id'});
            tinymce.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, 'your_editor_id' );
            }
        });
```